# Spring Data JPA remove child entities

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a load repository.

```
@Transactional
public interface MyLoadRepository extends CrudRepository<ParentEntity, Serializable> {
}
```

Then is my ParentEntity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

}
```

Then I have multiple child entities.

```
  @Entity
   @Table(name = "EntityA")
    public class EntityA extends ParentEntity {
    }



  @Entity
  @Table(name = "EntityB")
  public class EntityB extends ParentEntity {
  }
```

Ques : I want to delete these entities separately by my repository.

If I write something like this.

```
@Autowired
private MyLoadRepository repository;
```

and then `repository.deleteAll()`
I get error that repository is not entity (It obiviously not).
Here I want to delete either entityA or entityB data completely based on some condition. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

We should create repository per entity and not on non entity classes.

So, for your case you need 2 repository classes

```
@Transactional
public interface EntityARepo extends CrudRepository< EntityA, String> {
}

@Transactional
public interface EntityBRepo extends CrudRepository< EntityB, String> {
}
```

now in service classes you can do

```
@Autowired
private EntityARepo repoA;

@Autowired
private EntityBRepo repoB;
```

and then you can call delete method based on your condition

```
repoA.deleteAll()
```

or

```
repoB.deleteAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the entity based on a condition. For example, if the EntityA has a primary key uuid, then you must find EntityA by uuid and then delete the EntityA.

EntityA entityA = entityARepo.findOne(uuid);
repository.delete(entityA);

EntityB entityB = entityBRepo.findOne(uuid);
repository.delete(entityB);